# How to make a Calculator?

Tags: c, c++, calculator

I am new to electronics programming. I am currently using C#.

Can you please tell me how to programme a Calculator, what programming language should I use? Can I use C/C++?

And what components should I buy? Give me some good advice too, I am new to this...

Comment: There are literally hundreds of thousands of different approaches, some using microprocessors (which may or may not have a C/C++ compiler), some using PLCs, some using simpler "raw" components.

Comment: @TDHofstetter - Agreed. But before we close his question, can't we at least give Thong a few useful pointers? I've tried to do so in my answer.

Comment: Um... this question begged recommendations for specific products or places to purchase them, @Matt, @Leon? How do you figure that???

Comment: @TDHofstetter - Saying that the question is seeking recommendations for specific products or places to buying them is either a mistake - they chose the wrong ready-made message among the list given by the system - or it's just an excuse to close the question. To me, the original poster is actually asking for possible hardware designs for him to start with, but didn't know exactly how to ask that. I thought about editing the question to remove the *b-word*, but then one could argue that the question would be too broad - which was where you're getting at with your first comment.

Comment: @TDHofstetter - To me, the question isn't too broad either, if you don't dive into the details too soon. I think that's where you were getting at with your attempt at an answer, which is great. I think the question, althoug basic, is perfectly answerable and it leaves a good reference for the future.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way to make a simple calculator is to put together the following basic components:

- Keypad
- LCD or a set of 7-segments displays
- Microcontroller (MCU)
- Power supply

Basically, you'll have to program the MCU to control all these components. That can be done in C/C++, yes. You'll have to choose among the various kinds of MCUs available. Simpler ones to use are AVR, PIC. You can also use development boards like the Arduino.

You'll have to program the MCU to detect which keys are pressed from the keypad and display what's being typed in the LCD. Then, when an operation is completed, you'll have the MCU calculate the results and display it back into the display.

If that's your first electronics project, it may be a bit too complicated. I suggest you start off by researching and prototyping each component separately and then put them all together.

Here are a few links for you to get started:

- [Implementing a Calculator Using Peripherals Like a Keypad](http://esd.cs.ucr.edu/labs/calc/calc.html)
- [Simple calculator using avr microcontroller](http://avrprojects.info/avr-projects/simple-calculator-using-avr-microcontroller/)
- [Build a Fixed Point LED Calculator](http://lupinesystems.com/calc/)
- [Google search on how to build a calculator](https://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=electronics+calculator&safe=active&gws_rd=ssl#hl=en&q=how+to+make+a+calculator+microcontroller&safe=active)

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thong - As you go on learning more about each component, you'll have more questions. Fell free to ask them here. Your questions will become more specific and in time they will be better received by the users of the site. Don't mind the downvotes too much for now.